# Select Image From gallery and save it for future use

Tags: android, image, save

I am working on application and i want that the user can select images from gallery so that he can apply frames on it. I am successful in accessing mobile gallery, now i want to know how to save the selected image for further processing. The selected image will be used to apply frame on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for selecting image from gallery :

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setType=("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
/*Declare PICK_IMAGE globally :  private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;  */
```

Actual Code starts Here

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    switch (requestCode) {
    case PICK_IMAGE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            try {
                // OI FILE Manager
                String filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

                // MEDIA GALLERY
                String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

                if (selectedImagePath != null) {
                    filePath = selectedImagePath;
                } else if (filemanagerstring != null) {
                    filePath = filemanagerstring;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown path",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("Bitmap", "Unknown path");
                }

                if (filePath != null) {
                    Log.e("file path  ","file path "+filePath);
                    GlobalValues.camefromtw="true";
                    decodeFile(filePath);
                } else {
                    bitmap = null;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internal error",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
        break;protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    switch (requestCode) {
    case PICK_IMAGE:
        Log.e("result code","result code"+resultCode+"  result   "+Activity.RESULT_OK);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            try {
                // OI FILE Manager
                String filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

                // MEDIA GALLERY
                String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

                if (selectedImagePath != null) {
                    filePath = selectedImagePath;
                } else if (filemanagerstring != null) {
                    filePath = filemanagerstring;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown path",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("Bitmap", "Unknown path");
                }

                if (filePath != null) {

                    decodeFile(filePath);
                } else {
                    bitmap = null;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internal error",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
        break;
    default:
    }
```

Image is recieved in filepath now you can use it ,Here in this code i am using thi sto set ImageView

```
  public void decodeFile(String filePath) {

    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

    // The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;

    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;  
    }

    // Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);

    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First add this :

```
ImageView profile;
Bitmap bmp;
SharedPreferences sp;
public static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 1;
```

Then in onCreate method add these lines of code :

```
sp=getSharedPreferences("profilePicture",MODE_PRIVATE);
    profile=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profile);
    if(!sp.getString("dp","").equals("")){
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(sp.getString("dp", ""), Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
        profile.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
    }

profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openGallery();
        }
    });
```

Then add these function openGallery() :

```
private void openGallery() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ProfileActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ProfileActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
    }else {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
    }
}
```

Then add this , onRequestPermissionsResult() :

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_FROM_GALLERY:
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,"Not working",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //do something like displaying a message that he didn`t allow the app to access gallery and you wont be able to let him select from gallery
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

onActivityResult():

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try { // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
                bmp = BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile(imgDecodableString);
                profile.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
                sp.edit().putString("dp", encodedImage).commit();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }else {
        Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "You haven't picked Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to give permission in Manifest file.